# Master Theorem - $T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{4})+1$

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Hello Mathematics Community,

I tried to solve

$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{4})+1$

with the Master-Theorem.

$Case$ $3:$

$a=2$ ; $b=4$ ; $f(n)=1$

$n^{log_b\,a}$ $=$ $n^{log_42}=n^{0.5}$

Condition: $ f(n)\in \Omega(n^{log_ba+\epsilon)} \, for \, \epsilon>0 $

$= 1\in\Omega(n^{0.5+\epsilon}) $

$Let \, \epsilon>0$ ; $ \epsilon=0.5 $

$ 1\in \Omega(n) \ with \, \epsilon=0.5 $

$Condition\, 2:$

$af(\frac{n}{b})\leq cf(n)$

$= 2(\frac{n}{4})^1 \leq cn $

true for $c=1$

$\Rightarrow T(n) = \Theta(n) $

Is this true or is there a mistake ?

sincerely,
M.Hisoka

Comment: Note that $$x_n=2^{-n}T(4^n)$$ solves the recursion $$x_n=x_{n-1}+2^{-n}$$ hence $$x_n=x_0+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots+2^{-n}=x_0+1-2^{-n}$$ in particular $$x_n=\Theta(1)$$ hence $$T(4^n)=\Theta(2^n)$$ from which you are probably expected to deduce, although this is not a valid consequence, that $$T(n)=\Theta(\sqrt n)$$ Yes this does not use the Master Theorem and this requires that you use your brain (but somehow I cannot make myself see this as a defect of the method...).

Comment: @Did I am confused, is the complexity now $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ ?
Because $n^{log_42}=n^{1/2}=\sqrt{n}$ for n $\geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

$1$ isn't in $\Omega(n^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, it's in $O(n^{1/2-\varepsilon})$. Also $af(n/b) \le cf(n)$ is equivalent to $a \le c$ since $f(n) = 1$.